# HTTP/1.1 505 HTTP Version Not Supported: Processing (client) to Heroku app server

Tags: http, heroku, networking, processing

I'm trying to ultimately make a POST request from my local Processing application (using the Network library [1]) to a Heroku application I have set up. Right now, I'm just trying to make a simple GET request to make sure the two endpoints can connect.

```
c = new Client(this, <my-heroku-app-url>, 80);
c.write("GET / HTTP/1.1\n");
c.write("Host: example.com\n\n");
```

But I'm getting this response:

```
HTTP/1.1 505 HTTP Version Not Supported
Connection: close
Server: Cowboy
```

It works if I replace the url with any other normal site, like "www.ucla.edu," so I feel like it's specifically because I'm trying to access a Heroku application. I've verified Heroku supports HTTP 1.1 [2] and pretty sure it's serving from port 80, so now I'm not sure what's wrong?

[1] Processing network library: https://processing.org/tutorials/network/
[2] Heroku HTTP Routing: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing

Comment: try using regular '\r\n' instead of '\n' which is not the official end-of-line for HTTP ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah ok figured it out! Turns out it was a multitude of problems. Fixed the 505 thanks to @regilero, and the urls were also not quite right. Here's the format that worked:

```
c = new Client(this, "myapp.herokuapp.com", 80);
c.write("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n");
c.write("Host: myapp.herokuapp.com\r\n");
c.write("\r\n");
```

Comment: mark your answer as solving the problem, please, for future readers and to remove your question from unanswered questions.